# Question about a proof with moving plane method

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations

I am reading the book *Elliptic partial differential equations* by Q. Han and F. Lin. In the section 3.6 "Moving Plane Methods", I come across a trouble understanding the following step:

> **Lemma 2.35**  *Suppose that $\Omega$ is a bounded domain that is convex in the $x_1$ direction and symmetric with respect to the plane $\left\{x_1=0\right\}$. Suppose $u \in C(\bar{\Omega}) \cap$ $C^2(\Omega)$ is a positive solution of
> $$
> \begin{aligned}
> \Delta u+f(u)=0 & \text { in } \Omega, \\
> u=0 & \text { on } \partial \Omega,
> \end{aligned}
> $$
> where $f$ is locally Lipschitz in $\mathbb{R}$. Then $u$ is symmetric with respect to $x_1$ and $D_{x_1} u(x)<0$ for any $x \in \Omega$ with $x_1>0$.*

> PROOF: Write $x=\left(x_1, y\right) \in \Omega$ for $y \in \mathbb{R}^{n-1}$. We will prove
> $$
> u\left(x_1, y\right)<u\left(x_1^*, y\right)
> $$
> for any $x_1>0$ and $x_1^*<x_1$ with $x_1^*+x_1>0$. Then by letting $x_1^* \rightarrow-x_1$, we get $u\left(x_1, y\right) \leq u\left(-x_1, y\right)$ for any $x_1$. Then by changing the direction $x_1 \rightarrow-x_1$, we get the symmetry.
> Let $a=\sup x_1$ for $\left(x_1, y\right) \in \Omega$. For $0<\lambda<a$, define
> $$
> \begin{aligned}
> \Sigma_\lambda & =\left\{x \in \Omega: x_1>\lambda\right\}, \\
> T_\lambda & =\left\{x_1=\lambda\right\}, \\
> \Sigma_\lambda^{\prime} & =\text { reflection of } \Sigma_\lambda \text { with respect to } T_\lambda, \\
> x_\lambda & =\left(2 \lambda-x_1, \ldots, x_n\right) \text { for } x=\left(x_1, \ldots, x_n\right) .
> \end{aligned}
> $$
> In $\Sigma_\lambda$ we define
> $$
> w_\lambda(x)=u(x)-u\left(x_\lambda\right) \quad \text { for } x \in \Sigma_\lambda .
> $$
> **Then we have by the mean value theorem
> $$
> \begin{aligned}
> \Delta w_\lambda+c(x, \lambda) w_\lambda=0 & \text { in } \Sigma_\lambda, \\
> w_\lambda \leq 0 \text { and } w_\lambda \not \equiv 0 & \text { on } \partial \Sigma_\lambda,
> \end{aligned}
> $$
> where $c(x, \lambda)$ is a bounded function in $\Sigma_\lambda$.** We need to show $w_\lambda<0$ in $\Sigma_\lambda$ for any $\lambda \in(0, a)$. This implies in particular that $w_\lambda$ assumes along $\partial \Sigma_\lambda \cap \Omega$ its maximum in $\Sigma_\lambda$. **By Theorem 2.5 (the Hopf lemma)** we have for any such $\lambda \in(0, a)$
> $$
> \left.D_{x_1} w_\lambda\right|_{x_1=\lambda}=\left.2 D_{x_1} u\right|_{x_1=\lambda}<0 .
> $$

**My Qustion**

I bold the step that troubles me. When using the Hopf Lemma,

(1) $\Delta w_\lambda+c(x, \lambda) w_\lambda\geq0$

(2) $c(x,\lambda)\leq0$

are assumed, But the $c(x,\lambda)$ here is derived from the continuity of $f$ and the mean value theorem:
$$
f(u(x))-f(u(x_{\lambda}))=c(x,\lambda)(u(x)-u(x_{\lambda}))=c(x,\lambda)w_{\lambda}(x)
$$
And since $f$ is locally Lipschitz, we can deduce that $c(x,\lambda)$ is bounded, but I think $c(x,\lambda)\leq0$ cannot be implied directly.

Here is some of my manuscript:

We rewrite
\begin{equation}\tag{1}
\Delta w_{\lambda} + c(x,\lambda)w_{\lambda}=0
\end{equation}
as
$$
\Delta w_{\lambda} - c^-(x,\lambda)w_{\lambda}=- c^+(x,\lambda)w_{\lambda}
$$
But it seems that we don't have the fact that $w_{\lambda}\leq0$ in $\Sigma_{\lambda}$ to assure the assumption (2). Actually, the fact that $w_{\lambda}\leq0$ is what we essentially want to prove by doing this procedure.

Then I notice that it mentions that $c$ is bounded, which implies that there exists a constant $M$ such that
$$
\tilde{c}(x,\lambda):=c(x,\lambda)-M\leq0
$$
then
we can rewrite (1) as
$$
\Delta w_{\lambda} + \tilde{c}(x,\lambda)w_{\lambda}= - M w_{\lambda}.
$$
Now I come across the same question: I cannot assure both the assumptions (1) and (2) in Hopf Lemma.

I am not sure whether I am on the right way. Can anyone give me a hint? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the fact $\omega_{\lambda}\leq 0$ can be obtained from the condition $D_{x_1}u(x)<0$.